# regexp url javascript and in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this type of urls:

> http://localhost:8000/#/requests/5b0ac09ba8abbc6ef5238403/blue
>   http://localhost:8000/#/requests/5b0ac09ba8abbc6ef5238402/red
>   http://localhost:8000/#/requests/5b0ac09ba8abbc6ef5238403/pink

I would like to know a url to check this types of urls:

I'm trying with something like:

```
if (str.match(/^([a-z0-9]{24,})$/)) {
    alert("match!");
}
```

but i need to check full url to check if `currentUrl` is this type or another type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
if ((new RegExp('\#\/(?:requests)\/([0-9a-z]+)\/(?:[a-z]+)$','g')).test(str)) {
    alert('match!');
}
```